# How to delete old profiles with script

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to adapt this code I got from another post for the needs of my current organization. Please see below code:

```
$Admin = "Administrator","Public","Default","Administrator"

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem C:\Users\)
{
    if ($file -in $Admin)

        {
            Write-Host = "`r`nUser account is" $file ". This is an Administrator Account, it will not be deleted."
        }

    else

        {

            Write-Host = "`r`nUser account is" $file ". Checking profiles age..."
            $FileDate = (Get-item C:\Users\$file).CreationTime
            Write-Host = $FileDate 
            $TestDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-30)
            Write-Host = $TestDate

        If ($FileDate -lt $TestDate)

            {
                Write-Host = "Since" $file "is older than 30 Days (" $FileDate ") it will be deleted."
                $UserAccountPath = "C:\\Users\\$file"
                $WMIQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE localpath = '$UserAccountPath'"
                $UserProfile = get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | where localpath -eq c:\\users\\$file
                Remove-WmiObject -InputObject "$UserProfile"

            }

        else

            {
                Write-Host = "Since File is dated less than 30 days old (" $FileDate ") it will not need to be deleted."
            }

        }

}
```

After running this I get the following error:

```
Remove-WmiObject : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:28 char:17
+                 Remove-WmiObject -InputObject "$UserProfile"
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check that `$UserProfile` was not null before trying to `Remove-WmiObject`?

Comment: Hmm ... this may help ... [https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-delete-user-profile/](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-delete-user-profile/)

Comment: Here's a [Delete-UserProfile](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4908-delete-remote-user-profile) function.

Comment: I don't know why you're using two backslashes \\ with where-object.  Also, sometimes the profile has a different name like c:\users\myuser.1 etc.  You might try using the group policy instead.  Deleting a lot of profiles at once can throttle the cpu.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the mistake is in this line:

```
$UserProfile = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile | Where localpath -EQ c:\\users\\$file
```

`$UserProfile` is null, and **will always be null**, because the equality comparer `-eq` is looking for an exact match, to put it into perspective:

```
'C:\some\path' -eq 'C:\\some\\path' # => False

[pscustomobject]@{
    localPath = 'C:\some\path'
} | Where-Object localPath -EQ 'C:\\some\\path' # => Null
```

To fix this, you can do the following:

```
# $UserAccountPath = "C:\\Users\\$file" // This line is not needed
#
# DirectoryInfo objects have a FullName property for their Absolute Path
$UserProfile = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile | Where-Object localpath -EQ $file.FullName
Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $UserProfile
```

---

```
$UserProfile = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile | Where-Object localpath -EQ $file.FullName
$UserProfile.Delete()
```

Comment: I tried your fix by removing the unnecessary line and replacing those two other lines with what you mentioned. Now I get this error: `Remove-WmiObject : 
At line:26 char:17
+                 Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $UserProfile
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject` . Thank you for the quick response to my question.

Comment: @Dspikes can you try using the last code update?

Comment: I get this error when I use the latest code you posted: `Remove-WmiObject : 
At line:27 char:17
+                 Remove-WmiObject
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject`

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Remove-WmiObject function not working properly. I have no clue why though.

Comment: @Dspikes mm did you try running the script as administrator?

Comment: Yes I run PowerShell ISE as admin as well as setting the execution policy as unrestricted.

Comment: @Dspikes ok, what about using the `.Delete()` method, see my last edit

Comment: I get this error when I try your last edit `Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): ""
At line:28 char:17
+                 $UserProfile.Delete()
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

Comment: @Dspikes I'm sorry I have no idea what it could be. Both methods should be working.

Comment: No worries. I will continue to investigate why Remove-WmiObject function not working or the delete method.