# I'm having issues with removing profiles in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I have developed several scripts to remove unused profiles from machines with the exception of a few important accounts. Every script that I use always give me the same error when using the `Remove-WmiObject`, `Remove-CimInstance`, and `.Delete()`. I am certain that all of these scripts should work, but I receive the same error. Please see the below script and attached error. There is something wrong with my machine that is blocking me from using any of these functions. **So my question: Is there anything I can do to get these functions to work for me or troubleshoot the issue?** (I can attach other scripts and errors if needed)

**Script:**

```
$Admin = "Administrator","Public","Default","Administrator"

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem C:\Users\)
{
    if ($file -in $Admin)
    {
        Write-Host = "`r`nUser account is" $file ". This is an Administrator Account, it will not be deleted."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host = "`r`nUser account is" $file ". Checking profiles age..."
        $FileDate = (Get-item C:\Users\$file).CreationTime
        Write-Host = $FileDate 
        $TestDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-30)
        Write-Host = $TestDate
        If ($FileDate -lt $TestDate)
        {
            Write-Host = "Since" $file "is older than 30 Days (" $FileDate ") it will be deleted."
            $UserAccountPath = "C:\\Users\\$file"
            $WMIQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE localpath = '$UserAccountPath'"
            $UserProfile = get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | Where-Object localpath -EQ $file.FullName
            Remove-WmiObject -InputObject "$UserProfile"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host = "Since File is dated less than 30 days old (" $FileDate ") it will not need to be deleted."
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Remove-WmiObject : 
At line:28 char:17
+                 Remove-WmiObject -InputObject "$UserProfile"
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

My past post might help for some background info: [How to delete old profiles with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70793670/how-to-delete-old-profiles-with-script/70794037?noredirect=1#comment125174316_70794037)  .

Comment: So `Get-CimInstance .... | Remove-CimInstance` doesn't work you?

Comment: It does not. I can provide a script and the results using that command if you would like.

Comment: I suspect you have an issue with the WMI repository on that computer. Also which version of Windows are we talking about? Can you run this command in an admin elevated prompt? *winmgmt /verifyrepository* . Finally, are you able to delete one of the profile using the Windows GUI? If not, this would confirm an issue with WMI...

Comment: @ZivkoK So I am on Windows 10 and I did run the command and the response was "WMI repository is consistent". I am unable to delete profiles through the GUI because that is controlled by our group policy in my organization. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: There's a group policy that does it after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sidToRemove = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::BuiltinAdministratorsSid, $null).ToString()

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID = '$($sidToRemove)' AND SPECIAL = 'FALSE' AND LOADED = 'FALSE'" |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }
```

And you can not remove `public` and `default` profiles as they are not profiles actually.

Comment: So I ran the updated script with your changes and I did not recieve an error with it, but it did not delete any users.

Comment: I just replaced `$UserProfile = get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | Where-Object localpath -EQ $file.FullName
            Remove-WmiObject -InputObject "$UserProfile"'` With the code you posted.

Comment: Check if profile is not loaded and not special. 
Loaded profiles are non-deletable until unloaded. 
Special profiles should not be deleted.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a bit new to this. Is there an easy command to determine the loaded profiles on a machine? I remember I tried it once, but I have lost the code for it.

Comment: So I figured it out. I have 10 profiles on my test machine. All are loaded and only 2 of them are considered special. The script still should have removed 8 of them. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Loaded profiles should be unloaded. Reboot is the simplest way. Just wipe all profiles during startup script

Comment: So restarting the machine will unload the profiles? Also I apologize once again for me not knowing much. How would I run the script during the startup script?

Comment: There are tons of ways running script during startup: Scheduled task with trigger "At startup', local policies, group piolicies, tons of registry places where to place your scriptAnd yes, reboot will unload profiles.

Comment: Sorry for being a bother. I can figure out how to run the script on startup, but I rebooted the machine and all of the profiles are still loaded. Is this due to a group policy setting you think?

Comment: I think it should not happen for regular user profile. IDK what is the reason

Comment: I am still having issues with this if anyone has any more suggestions. I'm guessing its an issue with the WMI service or network group policy preventing me from using certain PS commands.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to add comments, but the answer provided by filimonic is the only way I've had success. I tried using copilot answers and also several things from google search results but they all error out.
Here is what I've done:

List user profiles and SIDs:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Select-Object SID, LocalPath
```

Copy the SID of the user profile I want to remove and put it in this command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID = '<SID for the user profile I want to remove>' AND SPECIAL = 'FALSE' AND LOADED = 'FALSE'" | ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }
```